# Mimicking results of form element outside of form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have this form:

```
    <form name="dateChooser" id="dateChooser">
        <select name="chooseMonth" id="calChooseMonth">...</select>
        <select name="chooseYear" id="calChooseYear">...</select>
    </form>
```

So on change #calChooseMonth/#calChooseYear I pass (this.form) as parameters to a function. Console logging (this.form) gives me this:

```
    <form name="dateChooser" id="dateChooser">
        <select name="chooseMonth" id="calChooseMonth">...</select>
        <select name="chooseYear" id="calChooseYear">...</select>
    </form>
```

[image]

I'm trying to pass that same form data outside of the form, so I can't use 'this'. I've tried:

```
      console.log($("form[name='dateChooser']"));
```

This returns an objective array of the form contents, which would work but the function I'm sending the data to is 3rd party and needs data in the format

```
      console.log($('#dateChooser').html());
```

Returns raw html which doesn't match the my (this.form) return

```
      console.log($('#dateChooser').form);
```

Returns undefined is not a function. Kinda hoped it'd be that simple.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference between "raw html" and what you've provided as the output of `this.form`. That (the output) looks like what I would call "raw html".

Comment: @PatrickQ I figured that'd be the case so I've included a image. http://i.imgur.com/u6FXJYK.png

Comment: How about this `console.log($("#dateChooser").get(0))`.

Comment: Are you sure you're tackling the right problem? It seems unlikely that a 3rd party function would want the HTML of your form. Shouldn't you be extracting the selected values and passing those?

Comment: @PatrickQ this works! Add it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @MikeW That's how I would do it- but I'm working on this project with a team and the other guy has a lot of code centered around this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method.

```
$("#dateChooser").get(0)
```

`.html()` returns the HTML that is *contained within* the given selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the select by just using

```
var month = $("#calChooseMonth").val();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ksa3F/)